# C# Compare strings in 5 text file and create new file having same string one time

Tags: c#, string, string-comparison

Hi i am working on my project and got some issues. I have 5 .text files consist of some strings. I want to compare strings in these 5 files and generate a new text file have all repeated strings in those 5 files written only one time.

Comment: Where is your code! What have you tried so far? SO is not a software writing service.

Comment: Agree with @MegaTron

Comment: Could you provide some examples?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very simple method

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;



namespace ConsoleApplication85
{
    class Program
    {
        static string[] fileNames = { "file1", "file2", "file3", "file4", "file5" };
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string> strings = new List<string>();
            foreach (string fileName in fileNames)
            {
                strings.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines);
            }
            File.WriteAllLines("file6", strings.Distinct);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: If file(s) is/are *large*, materialization (`List<string> strings`) is not a good choice.

Comment: Do you have another method for checking duplicates?  If there is a large number of duplicates it may make sense to do the distinct after each read instead of waiting until the end.

Answer (score 0):

Just a simple *Linq*:

```
  //TODO: put actual file names here
  String[] names = new String[] { "1.txt", "2.txt", "3.txt", "4.txt", "5.txt" };

  File.WriteAllLines("6.txt", names //TODO: put actual file name here
    .SelectMany(name => File.ReadLines(name))
    .Distinct());
```